# tinyxml include file error in vc++

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++, tinyxml

When I include tinyxml in my project it gives be error for

Error   1: error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tinyxml.h': No such file or directory.
Error   2: IntelliSense: cannot open source file "tinyxml.h".

My structure for code is as below!.What is wrong in it?![This is snapshot of my project and error][1]. Is there problem with project structure?

Comment: paste your 'tinyxml.h' in the directory where all other .h(header files) are placed.

Answer (score 2):

The *tinyxml.h* file is not in the include path, so as the error indicates, the compiler can't find that file.

You need to edit the project setting and in the compiler section find the include directories edit field and add the folder where the *tinyxml.h* is found to that list of directories.